# Dialog should resume other application or activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I am creating application that alert dialog when battery level is less than 10%.

It is displaying fine.

But I want that,

> When dialog is displayed, then current activity should be resumed and not paused, if dialog is there.

But, When dialog is displaying, current application goes in background(i.e. paused).

> I am displaying dialog from service, that implemented broadcast receiver for battery level. Hence, If any activity on top, then it should not be paused.(it can be any thing like game, normal activity or audio app on top)

Hence, Give me solution please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this is to show a Toast from you service [like this](http://techblogon.com/custom-toast-android-example-with-source-code-description/#),  instead of dialog . You can also customize your toast for better appearance [[see how]](http://techblogon.com/custom-toast-android-example-with-source-code-description/#)

Comment: But, I need buttons of "cancel" and "Launch Killer" in dialog. And Toast does not support click event or button inside it.

Comment: For showing buttons you need the context, which will call onPause in fore ground activity..